# Can Allergy and Auto-immune diseases be the signs of hyper-vigilant immune system?

Tags: cancer, autoimmune, allergies

Allergy sufferers are much less likely to get some types of cancers. Theories regarding  allergy - cancer link are mixed.

Many say it is due to hyper-sensitive immune response.  But the correlation between allergy and lowered glioma risk is also difficult to explain, due to blood -brain barrier.

However there was one interesting theory, saying that, allergy is an evolutionary anti-cancer protection. Allergy sufferers simply do not let some of the carcinogens to come into their body.

I am computer engineer. When we setup a protection at a system (antispam, antivirus, firewall) there is  **sensitivity** level that we have to select.  Higher sensitivity offers better protection but also results in more **false positives**.  However not all false positives are due to higher sensitivity. Some can simply be due to faulty protection system.

So my question is,  can  allergy or auto-immune diseases be sign of high-sensitive immune system which will have advantages and  disadvantages  or just a sign of simply faulty immune system which will have only disadvantages?

Comment: Could you add some citations of where you came across these theories?

Comment: @MattDMo  http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2012/02/20/jnci.djs153.full